# passing any-type parameter to function in c++ using template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to pass any-type parameter to my function `func1()`.
So here is my code:
**myclass.h** :

```
public:
   myclass();
   template<typename T> void func1(T object);
```

**myclass.cpp** :

```
template<typename T> 
void myclass::func1(T object)
{
    return;
}
```

**main.cpp** :

```
int a=0;
myclass::func1<int>(a);
```

But I got this error :

```
error: cannot call member function 'void myclass::func1(T) [with T = int]' without object
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: A member function is still a member function, even if it is a template. That means you need an *object* to call it on.

Comment: And if you haven't used templates before, then you might find [this question and its answers informative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: Also you should not be specifying the template type.  You should let template argument deduction work for you.

Comment: The instantiated function is not static, so you need an object instance to call it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK!... I create an object from myclass and I got this error `error: undefined reference to `void myclass::func1<int>(int)'`

Comment: For that see my second comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . I saw that question and answer, but I think that is not my answer, maybe I can't Understand where is the point exactly. would you answer my question with correct sample for `passing any-type parameter to function in c++ using template`. This way I can accept that for other people seeing this question. I prefer to use function without object instance.

Comment: @Thinkeye Putting `static` before my function declaration is enough?

Comment: You need to *define* the function in the header file, you can't split templates into header and source files like you normally do.

Comment: If you don't want to use an object instance, why define a class in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot simply separate declaration and definition in template functions. The simplest thing to do for a template function is to provide the code body in the function declaration in the header file.

If you want to call the function without a class object add static to the function signature.

header.hpp

```
#include <iostream>

class test_class{
public:
     template<typename T> static void member_function(T t){
        std::cout << "Argument: " << t << std::endl;
    }

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "header.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    test_class::member_function(1);
    test_class::member_function("hello");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but I wonder for declaration and definition separated simple example in template functions. If it's not possible then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @lord.h I don't think it's possible, but i am no expert. You can "trick" the compiler by having declarations and definitions in header and source files, and then include the source file in the end of the header file. I don't think i can explain any better from the already present answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file